# Reputation tab shows I earned 8 pts for upvote

Tags: support

I wrote an answer on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875725/like-operator-isnt-working-properly). In my reputation tab, it shows that I earned +10-2 = +8 votes for upvote on my answer. But when i see the question, there are no upvotes seen to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

One up (+10) minus one down (-2) equals a score of zero and 8 reputation gained...

Once you gain enough reputation ([that's 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), see [Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)) you can click the score next to a post. Then you'll see the separate up- and downvotes.

Your post is at +1 / -1:

[image: Plus one minus one]

That nets to 0.

Comment: How much score is required to view individual scores ?

Comment: 1000 reps needed to gain the Established User actions